# How do I upgrade my weapons in Bastion?

Tags: bastion

I've already started picking up items to upgrade my weapons in Bastion, however I have no idea how to actually upgrade my weapons.

Do I need to reach a certain point in the story to upgrade my weapons, and if so when? Finally, how *do* I upgrade my weapons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to build a forge in the Bastion. That option becomes available to you after completing the second mission.

Comment: You can't build the forge the first time you can build something.